# How to pre-build Python binaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, deployment, activestate

I am trying to deploy a Python environment as an RPM. Since the target systems may not have an Internet connection and/or a C compiler, going the download on the fly route may not work. The development environment is Python 2.7.10 with some modules installed via pip.

How do I pre-build the Python environment like [ActiveState](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveState) Python does?

Answer (score 3):

There's a tool called "PEX" which Twitter use to pre-compile a stack of Python code, plus libraries, module,s and support data into a single bundle.

It's a basically a zipped archive of a environment which will launch like it's an EXE file.

There are a few caveats -- one, it takes a while for them to start up. Two, the files will only work on the same version of Python you built them one -- if you have a hybrid 3.0/2.7/2.6 environment, it gets complicated.

PEX itself has a couple of outstanding gotchas around caching of installs and things.

Comment: Thanks! The target systems have RHEL 6 and 7. And I don't want to mess with system python. Right now I'm just installing in /opt/python directory and adding to path to reach it. I think PEX is more windows oriented. I'm more focused on linux right now. What do you think?

Comment: PEX is definitely a Linux-compatible tool. We use it so that we don't have to worry about version differences in our internal libraries breaking apps -- we know the app has a version of the library that it passed tests with. Twitter use (AFAICT) it so that they don't install all the support libs on each production machine -- they just push the pex to it and fire it up.

Comment: One *can* build PEXes which will run on hybrid systems -- I wrote a wrapper around the basic tool which will do just that; it compiles a PEX for each version of Python available on the buildserver and then merges them together into a single file which will launch on multiple Python platforms.

Comment: That sounds interesting and something i could use. How do I do that?